# How do I play games on a virtual machine?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization

So I have a powerful pc, i9-12900K, 64 gb ddr5 ram and a gtx 970. I want to install as main os Debian distro but I also want to play games as I was on a windows machine so I had the idea to create a windows virtual machine for gaming so is there any way to make my vm use the gpu power so I can play games ? I am using vmware workstation pro.

Comment: why that? I think that my question is totally acceptable. Thx

Comment: That should work .  You should have a very fast SSD drive .  You have enough memory and the CPU should be fast enough.  I am using VMware Workstation myself.  Graphics Processing comes from the VMware hardware system for the guest.  You would need to try it to see if fast enough.

Comment: You can use GPU passthrough.  Search for instructions.

Comment: Thx, this is exactly what I was searching.

Comment: Which games? I am not aware of a single hypervisors that supports DX12 or Vulcan. Even if you use VT-d you still can't use DX12 and Vulcan within the hyervisor.

Comment: You don't want VMware workstation for this.  I'd suggest taking a look here: https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/  which is full of info for what you're looking to do.  Also, steam has Proton for playing Windows games on Linux.